# Jsoup parsing an Html file with a tbody tag

Tags: jsoup

I just recently a inconsistent Jsoup behavior when it comes to the tbody tags,
When I'm parsing a distant page on the web with a Html structure like:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
     <tr><td>... text
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Jsoup does not include the tbody element in the elements returned by the select method().

I use the method connect().get() to load the remote page in a Document variable like:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
String expr = "table>tr>td";
String parsedTxt = doc.select(expr).text();
```

But when I parsed the same page on my local disk (after I downloading it). Jsoup includes the tbody tag. My expression will not work anymore because it's missing the tbody element.

I use:

```
File input = new File(locationOfFile);
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "");
```

My Jsoup expression works only in the first case.

Is there a way to force Jsoup to recognize the tbody element (or to remove it) so the same expression can used in both cases?

Is this a normal behavior from Jsoup?

Should I be using the connect method in parsing the local page as well?

Comment: What version of jsoup are you using? 1.6.0?

Comment: I still had the problem in version 1.5.2. I downloaded the new 1.6.0 friday but it did not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the browser you used to save the file included/created `tbody` tags when it saved the file. Which browser did you use to save the file to your desktop?

I would try downloading the file manually using `curl` or `wget` and then trying the parse from file.

Comment: I am using Mozilla Firefox on a Windows machine. I also forgot to mention I am using Firebug 1.7.2 plugin to view the html structure of the page. I just tried downloading the page with the wget. After opening the downloaded page the tbody tag is present.

Comment: Instead of using the expression "table>tr>td" would "table tr>td" work. In other words, if I tried to fetch the childs nodes descending from the table element instead of trying to fetch the direct childs maybe in could work in both cases?

Comment: you could also use the `table>tr>td, table>tbody>tr>td` selector to make sure to catch both things.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inspecting the element with firebug try to search for in the source (Show page source).
You should try to print/inspect

```
Document.html()
```

and see if JSOUP actually got the whole html.
If it did then the next step would be to report it on JSOUP https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues

If it did not (which is most likely), you should try adding additional headers to your get request( like user-agent and cookies). AJAX could also be the problem in which case you should use Selenium http://seleniumhq.org

Answer (score 0):

You can try [**`Jsoup 1.7.3`**](http://jsoup.org/download). It works for your situation. The sample code is following.

```
    String html
            = "<table>\n"
            + "<tbody>\n"
            + "<tr><td>... text.\n"
            + "</tbody>\n"
            + "</table>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements eles = doc.select("tbody > tr > td");

    for (Element ele : eles) {
        System.out.println(ele.toString());

    }
```

The result is this:

```
    <td>... text. </td>
```