# Jsoup allow <table> but no <tbody>

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to parse a HTML document using [jsoup](/questions/tagged/jsoup) and I want to allow `<table>` tag but not allow `<tbody>`.

I have seen this link:

[Jsoup parsing an Html file with a tbody tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387110/jsoup-parsing-an-html-file-with-a-tbody-tag)

and I tried with

```
Whitelist whiteList = Whitelist.relaxed();

whiteList.addTags("table");
whiteList.addTags("font");

whiteList.addAttributes("table", "align");
whiteList.addAttributes("tr","align");

//whiteList.removeTags("tbody");

String html = "<table>"
    + "<tr align='top'>"
    + "<th><font>Link</th>"
    + "</tr>"
    + "</table>";

boolean valid = Jsoup.isValid(html, whiteList);

System.out.println(valid);
```

If I remove the commented line I am getting `false`.

Also changing it to:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html,"",Parser.xmlParser());
```

doesn't have much of an effect.

Is there any workaround for this?

I want to allow `<table>` but not allow `<tbody>`.

PS - I have thought of checking for `<tbody>` before parsing but it is somehow not a very good solution I feel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: You can't do it with Jsoup right now.

**Explanation:**

According to the [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-table-element) that the [Jsoup parser](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/) (DOM builder) follows, it creates `tbody` elements automatically upon reading in a `tr` that is inside a `table` but not yet inside a `tbody`

Here is the relevant sectoin of the docu:

> ***tr = table . insertRow( [ index ] )***
>
> Creates a tr element, **along with a
>   tbody if required**, inserts them into the table at the position given
>   by the argument, and returns the tr.

It follows that Jsoup internally will create the tbody element for HTML content. If you use the XML parser, that `tbody` element is not created. Unfortunately the `Whilelist` feature only works on HTML, not on XML. You may issue a request for an implementation of the whiltelist feature for XML on the [JSoup issue list](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/).

Comment: Thanks for this reference.Will have to think of a workaround.